Devnagari of Plasma word
I am trying to write plasma in Devnagari and ``{\dn  =lAjmA}'', please can you suggest how to write half word of j in प्लाज्मा.

Your question is very unclear, you do not need to use a latin transliteration, to typeset प्लाज्मा you should be able to type प्लाज्मा but it isn't clear what you tried.

see for example the Marathi examples here https://www.learnlatex.org/mr/language-01

You had also asked this as an answer on another question.  It's not clear to me if you've tried the other answer to that question.

Welcome to the site! Are you able to use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?
